# Linux Mint 17.1 installation

Tags: linux-mint, boot

I have been trying to install mint 17.1, but all I can see is a blank screen with just mouse pointer. I had even tried to  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, so I don't know which commands to enter from that spot. Can anyone please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have read rave reviews of Mint but have never got on with it - suffice to say my user name was "is-mint-pants?" and my password was "mintispants" (and you must remember that in the UK what the Americans call "pants" we call "trousers"; "pants", over here, are an undergarment worn to protect the "fundamental" areas of the trousers' groin & buttock from soilage).  However, Mint doesn't recognize either of these any longer!

It seems to me that there are two points to be made:

1) Quote "I have been trying to install mint 17.1, but all I can see is a blank screen with just mouse pointer."
From what are you installing?  Is it a DVD from a magazine cover or is it a download from the internet?  Is it a CD, DVD, Thumbdrive?  Have you tried running **md5sum**?  On what are you installing it?  All this stuff (and a lot more) is very important.

2)  Why ask here?
Why not go to http://community.linuxmint.com/#?

OK! My favourite solution would be to bin Mint & try some other distro; but, failing that, there are other things you might try:
**a**)  Go to the Mint website (see above), download another copy & try again.
**b**)  If that doesn't work, try to log on to the Mint community and see what they come up with - but this time, give them the info listed @ **1** (above)
**c**)  Failing all of that, I suppose you could try here again

Good luck

dmk

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Linux Mint most successfully by downloading the .iso image from linuxmint.com and burning it to a DVD with Brasero. If you're using a Windows PC to download the .iso image, then Power ISO and Imgburn also work well. If burning .iso images is new to you - here are some tips - use a quality DVD (I use Verbatim disks)- check with md5sum or with the image burner's checksum. My experience with Mint and Ubuntu is that if you burn the .iso image correctly, the install goes flawlessly. Another option is to use OSDiscs.com - you get the disk for about $6 and I have had good luck with this method as well. But it's educational to learn how to burn an .iso image yourself - then you can download and try multiple distros whenever you like. Good Luck.